# Loading fonts to customize Material-UI theme in Next.js not working

Tags: fonts, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to add different fonts to my theme.js while using Material-UI in Next.js. It's been surprisingly difficult to figure out how.

I've tried using fontfaceobserver as suggested here(https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/512), but can't get the theme to update. Here's my theme.js file:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Raleway','Roboto Condensed',
    ].join(','),
    fontWeight: 700,
    h1:{
      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
      fontWeight: 700,
    }
  },
});
```

The font for my h1 doesn't change :(

Answer (score 13):

Anyone in Nextjs 13, do this for local fonts (works the same with Google fonts):

In `theme.config.tsx`

```js
import localFont from "@next/font/local";
import { NextFont } from "@next/font";
    
const customFont: NextFont = localFont({
  src: "../public/fonts/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf",
  display: "swap",
});
    
const theme = createTheme({
    
typography: {
    fontFamily: customFont.style.fontFamily,
  },
});
    
export const ThemeConfig: React.FC<ThemeProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: thats a nice approach! I will try that, thank you!

Comment: the code works, but it breaks my storybook setup. If you also used storybook have you changed anything specific in your storybook config to enable the fonts also there?

Comment: No i'm not using storybook and never used it before.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add a self-hosted font to your next.js project

Copy your-font.ttf into public/fonts folder

Create a new css file e.g your-font.css (in public/fonts/) and add this code to it :

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'your-font';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('./your-font.ttf');
}
```

Go to page/_document.js and add this line inside `<Head>` tag

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/your-font.css" />
```

Create a theme.js file for material ui and add your font to Typography :

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    
const theme = createMuiTheme(
  {
    typography: {
      fontFamily: [
        'your-font',
        'Arial',
        '-apple-system',
        'BlinkMacSystemFont',
        '"Segoe UI"',
        'Roboto',
        '"Helvetica Neue"',
        'sans-serif',
        '"Apple Color Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
      ].join(','),
    },
  },
);

export default theme;
```

Go to pages/_app.js and add your theme e.g :

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../common/theme';//location of theme file created in previous step
    
export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> {/*<---- Add this */}
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
    
MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 5):

For whoever comes this way, the answer was actually in the Material-ui and Next.js example project I was using:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js

You can see how google fonts get imported:

```js
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
          <meta name="emotion-insertion-point" content="" />
          {this.props.emotionStyleTags}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

based on this [tutorial](https://dev.to/elisabethleonhardt/self-hosted-fonts-with-nextjs-and-material-ui-b3k)

**global.css**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: GothamMedium;
  src: url("/fonts/GothamRnd-Medium.woff2");
  format: ("woff2");
  font-display: swap;
}
```

**Use your font inside MUI**

```js
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

export let theme = createTheme({});

function MyApp({ Component }) {
  return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Typography>Hello world from typography component</Typography>
            <p>Hello world from paragraph tag</p>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**use the same name for the font you used earlier in the CSS:**

```js
export let theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "GothamMedium, sans-serif",
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You did well with your **theme.js** file, so your next step should be creating a **Layout** component or use your **_app.js** file to provide your custom theme. It will as below.

in your **Layout** component.

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  {children}
  <h1>MY TEXT</h1> // now this h1 tag will be displayed with your font
</ThemeProvider>
```

for more information
https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set custom font in nextjs using `local` from `next/font/local` with MUI theme setup. Even if you UI package is separate from the app you just set the nextJs way of font and then `inherit` in the theme setup.

1. Theme Setup

```js
// Theme.ts .e.g in Mui Joy flavour
export const theme = extendTheme({
  fontFamily: {
    display: 'inherit', // 'Poppins set in _app.tsx
    body: 'inherit',
  },
});
```

2. Download and set fonts in any app dir .e.g  with `src/fonts/poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf,Poppins-SemiBold.ttf`
3. In your NextJs

```js
// _app.tsx

const poppinsFont = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: '../fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: '../fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf',
      weight: '600',
      style: 'semibold',
    },
  ],
});

// ... other app file
return getLayout(
    <main className={poppinsFont.className}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to use  MUI with NextJS is to  import font to mui them with next/local then use it in Components:

```
 //theme.ts

    import localFont from "next/font/local";

      const myFont=localFont({src:[path:....]})

       const muiTheme = createTheme({
         components: {
          MuiContainer: {
            styleOverrides: {
              root: {
               fontFamily: myFont.style.fontFamily,
                    },
                           },
                       },
                     },
                                    });
```